# Compare strings to identify duplicates

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, duplicates

I have to write an isDup function to compare two tweets based on their similar word counts to determine if the tweets are duplicate, based on a decimal threshold chosen (0-1).

My process is to write a sub with two hardcoded tweets my prof has provided (just to get an understanding before converting to a function). I encountered a run time error 5.

```
Option Explicit
Sub isDup()
    Dim tweet1 As String
    Dim tweet2 As String
    Dim threshold As Double
        threshold = 0.7

    tweet1 = "Hours of planning can save weeks of coding"
    tweet2 = "Weeks of programming can save you hours of planning"

    Dim tweet1Split() As String
        tweet1Split = Split(tweet1, " ")

    Dim tweet2Split() As String
        tweet2Split = Split(tweet2, " ")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim sameCount As Integer

    'my thought process below was to compare strings i and j to see if equal, and if true add 1 to sameCount,
    'but the If StrComp line is where the error is

    For i = LBound(tweet1Split) To UBound(tweet1Split) Step 1
        For j = LBound(tweet2Split) To UBound(tweet2Split) Step 1
            If StrComp(i, j, vbDatabaseCompare) = 0 Then
                sameCount = sameCount + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
   'here i wanted to get a total count of the first tweet to compare, the duplicate tweet is true based on the number of
   'similar words
    Function totalWords(tweet1 As String) As Integer
            totalWords = 0
        Dim stringLength As Integer
        Dim currentCharacter As Integer

            stringLength = Len(tweet1)

        For currentCharacter = 1 To stringLength

        If (Mid(tweet1, currentCharacter, 1)) = " " Then
            totalWords = totalWords + 1
        End If

        Next currentCharacter
    End Function

    'this is where i compute an "isDup score" based on similar words compared to total words in tweet1, in this
    'example the threshold was stated above at 0.7
    Dim score As Double
        score = sameCount / totalWords

    If score > threshold Then
        MsgBox "isDup Score: " & score & " ...This is a duplicate"
    Else
        MsgBox "isDup Score: " & score & " ...This is not a duplicate"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: At what line does the error appear?

Comment: I run the sub, get the error and press debug, and this line is highlighted as error      
If StrComp(i, j, vbDatabaseCompare) = 0 Then

Comment: i and j are indexes i.e. you are comparing indexes, not your strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First issue:

`i` and `j` are just indexes. You want to compare the string that your index relates to so:

```
If StrComp(tweet1Split(i), tweet2Split(j), vbDatabaseCompare) = 0 Then
```

---

### Second issue:

As noted in Microsoft documentation for [StrComp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function), `vbDatabaseCompare` is reserved for Access, which you are not using, hence the source of your second error. You need to switch to a different comparison

Comment: ah okay thank you that makes more sense. I updated the code, and i am still getting an error on that same line, same error (run time error 5). Could there be another issue with the entire code possibly

Comment: The issue now is vbDatabaseCompare. You are not using access. You need to use a different compare option. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function

Comment: wow such a stupid little mistake, that fixed that line thank you so much! If you happen to notice anything else, or see any other errors, let me know I'd appreciate it!

Comment: thanks i will im just looking at another issue, my prof has a different solution for the Function totalWords that i have, i found that code online. He has uploaded this as a template but i am still confused with it, " Dim score As Double
    If UBound(tweet1Split) > UBound(tweet2Split) Then
        'compute the isDup score
    Else
        'compute the isDup score
    End If"

Comment: that is a totally different issue and deserves a new question. Stack Overflow helps with specific questions. If questions were allowed to forever evolve & change, there would be no final accepted solution.